# External audio not working (Ear phone jack) in a Dell Inspiron 3542 after update

Tags: sound

When I type in the terminal `alsactl restore` (which has fixed this problem in the past) I got the response

```
alsactl restore

alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists

Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel Haswell HDMI" "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000" "0x1028" "0x0651"

Hardware is initialized using a generic method

Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC3234" "HDA:10ec0255,10280651,00100002" "0x1028" "0x0651"

Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Comment: The line `alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists` says that a lock file exists (it prevents to run several instances of an application). Did you kill the last working `alsactl restore`? Do you remember what was the output when `alsactl restore` was working?

Comment: After rebooting, the problem stopped. When I registered this problem, I had logged out and in and it didn't stop the problem. After shutting down the computer for the night and restarting it every thing was okay. Thanks for your help and sorry I didn't try to reboot the system first before logging the problem